# do we need a package like spatie for Permissions and Roles with Django

Tags: django, laravel, permissions, roles

i am new with Django, and I have been using Spatie with Laravel for a long time, my question is does I need to use something like it with Django? or even do I need to do anything about multi roles and permission with Django since the admin panel looks perfect and completed already..... Thanks

Comment: Django's builtin authentication package has `Group`s and `Permission`s, so this is already builtin. The "role"s of Spatie are thus (likely) what are `Group`s in Django.

Comment: so, we do not need to change it or develop it even with the advanced projects?

Comment: You can define one yourself, but Django has an app that is part of the Django package that already handles it, so unless you want to do something (very) sophisticated, it is not necessary to roll your own.